# How do I test Util class include android.os.Environment.getexternalstoragedirectory().getPath()

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing, robolectric

I'd like to test (Local unit tests) my app's utils class.
I have a problem to test some utils class include android.* class.

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.app.Application`

I know that using Roboletric provide me android os class but how to use in my case?

**FileUtilsTest.java**

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class FileUtilsTest {
    @Test
    public void getVideoDir() throws Exception {
        File videoDir = FileUtils.getVideoDir();

        //Never null
        assertThat("never null", videoDir, notNullValue());

        //Check the dir exist
        assertThat("Is exist", videoDir.exists(), is(true));
    }

....
}
```

**FileUtils.java**

```
public class FileUtils {

　　private static final String DIR_VIDEO = "/sample/note/video";
    public static File getVideoDir() {
        File dir = new File(getVideoPath());
        dir.mkdirs();
        return dir;
    }

    public static String getVideoPath() {
        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + DIR_VIDEO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out by myself.I forgot to add one line below.

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
```